# How can you disable SSL verification in urlib3?

Tags: python, url, python-requests

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adminko/.geonodevirtaulenvs/geonode/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/adminko/.geonodevirtaulenvs/geonode/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/adminko/.geonodevirtaulenvs/geonode/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/adminko/.geonodevirtaulenvs/geonode/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 416, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/home/adminko/.geonodevirtaulenvs/geonode/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/home/adminko/.geonodevirtaulenvs/geonode/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1131)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adminko/.geonodevirtaulenvs/geonode/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/home/adminko/.geonodevirtaulenvs/geonode/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/adminko/.geonodevirtaulenvs/geonode/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.example.com', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=qazqoinau_test%3A%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD&STYLES=qazqoinau_test%3Alayers_border_RK&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&TILED=true&access_token=JNkYj4bIfuWQbQu06AAF2MUxc9banx&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&BBOX=2504688.542848654%2C2504688.542848654%2C5009377.08569731%2C5009377.08569731 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1131)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/adminko/.geonodevirtaulenvs/geonode/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/adminko/.geonodevirtaulenvs/geonode/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url,verify=False,**kwargs)
  File "/home/adminko/.geonodevirtaulenvs/geonode/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/adminko/.geonodevirtaulenvs/geonode/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/adminko/.geonodevirtaulenvs/geonode/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 563, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.example.com', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=qazqoinau_test%3A%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD&STYLES=qazqoinau_test%3Alayers_border_RK&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&TILED=true&access_token=JNkYj4bIfuWQbQu06AAF2MUxc9banx&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&BBOX=2504688.542848654%2C2504688.542848654%2C5009377.08569731%2C5009377.08569731 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1131)')))
```

How can I disable checking this SSL verification or how can I handle this error (consequences after changing )? I am ready to change package code to handle this error. Everything was working when I was using HTTP connection.

I have already changed `request.get(verify = False)`

my code

```
import requests
requests.get('https://www.example.com:8080/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=qazqoinau_test%3A%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD&STYLES=qazqoinau_test%3Alayers_border_RK&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&TILED=true&access_token=JNkYj4bIfuWQbQu06AAF2MUxc9banx&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&BBOX=2504688.542848654%2C2504688.542848654%2C5009377.08569731%2C5009377.08569731')
```

Comment: This question is lacking any code or context (what version of urllib3? What code are you running?) See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `example.com` doesn't serve anything on 8080 - I'm assuming you've replaced a sensitive URL with `https://example.com` but even then it would be really weird to serve HTTPS over port 8080. Are you sure you didn't mean to use port 443?

Comment: I have running service on 8080 port and I should get some responses from it

Comment: Is your service running *HTTP* on 8080, or *HTTPS* on 8080? You can't request an SSL connection from an unencrypted endpoint - this is probably why you're getting an SSL version error.

Comment: it is running on https

Comment: I'm with @LayneBernardo on this.  I tried `requests.get('https://www.google.com:80/`)` (i.e. requesting SSL from a non-SSL port) and got the same error traceback as above.  I don't believe you're running SSL on port 8080.

Comment: If you get a proper response from `8080` when using `http`, then you are not running HTTPS on the port. Port 8080 is used almost exclusively (by convention) for HTTP services. You can't run both on the same port, it's either HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: @LayneBernardo sorry, I have tested. You are right. How can handle that?

Comment: If you want to actually use HTTPS, you will need to configure your service with an SSL certificate and setup a HTTPS endpoint - probably on 443 but you could really use whatever port you want. I would avoid 8080 (since as I mentioned, it's conventional to use this for HTTP), but you could use, e.g., 8443. How you actually do this will depend on what you're using to host the service. If you just want to handle this without crashing, I would use a `try...except` block as described at https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp